# Cannot listen to an asterisk manager event : QueueMemberPause

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am using nest js and asterisk manager for a call-center/CRM software. What i need to do is find out if an extension is on a break by emmiting its status on real time.

```
    this.ami.on('QueueMemberPause', async (evt) => {
      console.log(1, evt);
    });

    this.ami.on('managerevent', async (evt) => {
      if (evt.interface == 'Local/${exampleExtension}@from-queue/n') {
        console.log(evt);
      }
```

Here i am listening to 2 events : QueueMemberPaused and managerevent, the manager event reads the condition and logs the evt as :

```
{
  event: 'QueueMemberPause',
  privilege: 'agent,all',
  queue: '<someQueueNumber>',
  membername: '<someName>',
  interface: 'Local/<someExtension>@from-queue/n',
  stateinterface: 'hint:<someExtension>@ext-local',
  membership: 'static',
  penalty: '0',
  callstaken: '0',
  lastcall: '0',
  lastpause: '<time>',
  incall: '0',
  status: '5',
  paused: '0',
  pausedreason: '',
  ringinuse: '0',
  wrapuptime: '0',
  reason: '<breakReason>'
}
```

even though the event read from manager event is QueueMemberPause, why is my event listener on QueueMemberPause just above the managerevent not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your SDK show all events or just make on asterisk

```
asterisk -r
manager set debug on
```

And see all events available.

But your exact SDK(node.js?) may just change event name to be lowercase or upcase.

ps Can confirm that in asterisk source code it is with capitals:

```
apps/app_queue.c:2191:  return queue_member_to_ami("QueueMemberPause", message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, for listening the event, event names should in in lower case. I don't know this applies for newer versions of Asterisk but this was the case in Asterisk 16. working:

```
  this.ami.on('queuememberpause', async (evt) => {})
```